# How can I remotely stream videos to my tablet?

Tags: video, tablet, remote, stream

I'd like to be able to watch my videos that I keep on my desktop running Ubuntu 12.04.2 on my tablet (Nexus 7) when they're connected to  different networks. For example, when I'm at my girlfriend's house, and I've left my computer running at home.

Can anybody either walk me through how to set this up, or recommend an app that will do this for me? I'd prefer a free option if possible!
I tried Plex Media Server, but I can't access the in-browser manager any more for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two options. first you can start a vpn server, so you and your girl friend can be in one network range, then you can use some simple video streaming software like vlc to stream videos. second you must look for some p2p video streaming software. anything that will make you able to browse and choose. I haven't seen any ;)